# popup when cursor moves on image

Tags: html

How to make a prog. for popup window when mouse cursor moves over a specific area of the image a liitle window (popup) should open. when another area of same image different popup should open.

Answer (score 0):

> Using an unordered list, a couple of images, and a little CSS, we can
>   create an accessible "image map" with pop-up tool tips that provide
>   our readers more information on the links the map contains.

http://csshowto.com/effects/css-image-maps-with-pop-up-tool-tips/